# MySQL Multiple subqueries, get first value of a specific column for each day in a date interval

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have been stuck on the following query for some time and can't figure out how to do it (explanation below):

```
SELECT 
a.id, a.name, t.agency_id, t.initial_amount,
DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, "%d.%m.%Y") as date,
DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as date_created,
t.created_at, t.collection, t.pay, (t.initial_amount + t.collection - t.pay) as total_amount
FROM (
 SELECT
    hh.agency_id, hh.amount, h0.initial_amount, hh.created_at,
    SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=0,hh.amount,0)) AS collection,
    SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=1,hh.amount,0)) AS pay
 FROM house_register AS hh
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT h1.initial_amount, h1.agency_id, h1.created_at 
    FROM house_register AS h1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT min(h2.id) AS min_id, h2.agency_id, h2.created_at
        FROM house_register AS h2 
        GROUP BY h2.agency_id
    ) AS min_id_ag
        ON h1.agency_id = min_id_ag.agency_id
        AND h1.id = min_id_ag.min_id
) AS h0 
    ON hh.agency_id = h0.agency_id
WHERE hh.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' 
GROUP BY hh.created_at, hh.agency_id WITH ROLLUP
) AS t 
INNER JOIN agencies as a
on a.id = t.agency_id
```

So, what I'm trying to achieve here is getting a report from a certain period of time from a single table, in this table I have operations that have a type status(payment or collection) and each operation corresponds to a `agency_id` (store).

My report has to be something like this:

Columns:

```
agency_id    date X  initial_amount_of_first_transaction_of_day_in_loop sum(payments) sum(collection)
```

Rows will  look something like this:

```
agency_1 2015-01-01 500 100 0
agency_2 2015-01-01 600 100 0
.... next date
agency_1 2015-01-02 600 0 150
agency_2 2015-01-02 450 0 150
etc
```

What I want is to get the initial_amount of the first transaction (hence the `min(id)`) for each date grouped by `agency_id` and `created_at`. For example if I have 50 transactions on the date 2015-01-01, I want to get the value of the column `initial_amount` of the first transaction in that date.

Now it just selects the minimum value of the whole date interval. And I the same minimum value for all the dates.

Hope I was clear enough.

Thank you for the help!

Update Structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `house_register` (
`id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`created_at` date DEFAULT NULL,
`created_time` time DEFAULT NULL,
`initial_amount` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`document_type` tinyint(3) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`document_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`document_number` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`description` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
`amount` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`final_amount` decimal(14,2) DEFAULT NULL,
`agency_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
`user_id` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
`payment_type` tinyint(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 - incasare, 1 - plata',
`number` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`debit_account` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`credit_account` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
`short_desc` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=34;
```

Update query breakdown with result set:

The complete one returns this:
[Results complete sql](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznFME0XJpHWaEltc2ZMNTZDVU0/view?usp=sharing)

Subquery 1: [Subquery 1 results](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznFME0XJpHWYnF2cTRsbGRaZHc/view?usp=sharing)

```
SELECT
hh.agency_id, hh.amount, h0.initial_amount, hh.created_at,
SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=0,hh.amount,0)) AS collection,
SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=1,hh.amount,0)) AS pay
FROM house_register AS hh
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT h1.initial_amount, h1.agency_id, h1.created_at 
FROM house_register AS h1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT min(h2.id) AS min_id, h2.agency_id, h2.created_at
    FROM house_register AS h2 
    GROUP BY h2.agency_id
) AS min_id_ag
    ON h1.agency_id = min_id_ag.agency_id
    AND h1.id = min_id_ag.min_id
) AS h0 
ON hh.agency_id = h0.agency_id
WHERE hh.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' 
GROUP BY hh.created_at, hh.agency_id WITH ROLLUP;
```

Subquery 2:See comment

```
SELECT h1.initial_amount, h1.agency_id, h1.created_at 
FROM house_register AS h1
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT min(h2.id) AS min_id, h2.agency_id, h2.created_at
    FROM house_register AS h2 
    GROUP BY h2.agency_id
) AS min_id_ag
    ON h1.agency_id = min_id_ag.agency_id
    AND h1.id = min_id_ag.min_id;
```

Subquery 3:See comment

```
SELECT min(h2.id) AS min_id, h2.agency_id, h2.created_at
    FROM house_register AS h2 
    GROUP BY h2.agency_id;
```

Comment: could be show your structure !!

Comment: Subquery 2 results: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznFME0XJpHWOW1ZRWRseGVxaGs/view?usp=sharing)
Subquery 3 results: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznFME0XJpHWVkpJem1taExUOUU/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, yes, I had to re-read your question a couple of times, but I think I've got it sorted. Does this give you the results you require?

For the `min(h2.id)` select you need to `group by` `h2.created_at` also, not just the `h2.agency_id` - full group by = `GROUP BY h2.agency_id, h2.created_at` at line 18.

```
SELECT 
a.id, a.name, t.agency_id, t.initial_amount,
DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, "%d.%m.%Y") as date,
DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as date_created,
t.created_at, t.collection, t.pay, (t.initial_amount + t.collection - t.pay) as total_amount
FROM (
 SELECT
    hh.agency_id, hh.amount, h0.initial_amount, hh.created_at,
    SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=0,hh.amount,0)) AS collection,
    SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=1,hh.amount,0)) AS pay
 FROM house_register AS hh
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT h1.initial_amount, h1.agency_id, h1.created_at 
    FROM house_register AS h1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT min(h2.id) AS min_id, h2.agency_id, h2.created_at
        FROM house_register AS h2 
        GROUP BY h2.agency_id, h2.created_at
    ) AS min_id_ag
        ON h1.agency_id = min_id_ag.agency_id
        AND h1.id = min_id_ag.min_id
) AS h0 
    ON hh.agency_id = h0.agency_id
WHERE hh.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' 
GROUP BY hh.created_at, hh.agency_id WITH ROLLUP
) AS t 
INNER JOIN agencies as a
on a.id = t.agency_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to add the date (created_at) to the group by as days, and the where clause for between dates.

```
        WHERE h2.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' 
        GROUP BY h2.agency_id, date_format(h2.created_at, "%Y-%b-%d")
```

First line cuts down the search criteria to just the dates you want.
The second line groups everything by agency_id, and then the day (by grouping on created_at formatted YYY-MM-DD.

i.e. something like (I haven't tested but...)

```
SELECT 
a.id, a.name, t.agency_id, t.initial_amount,
DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, "%d.%m.%Y") as date,
DATE_FORMAT(t.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") as date_created,
t.created_at, t.collection, t.pay, (t.initial_amount + t.collection - t.pay) as total_amount
FROM (
 SELECT
    hh.agency_id, hh.amount, h0.initial_amount, hh.created_at,
    SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=0,hh.amount,0)) AS collection,
    SUM(IF(hh.payment_type=1,hh.amount,0)) AS pay
 FROM house_register AS hh
 LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT h1.initial_amount, h1.agency_id, h1.created_at 
    FROM house_register AS h1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT min(h2.id) AS min_id, h2.agency_id, h2.created_at
        FROM house_register AS h2 
        WHERE h2.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' 
        GROUP BY h2.agency_id, date_format(h2.created_at, "%Y-%b-%d")
    ) AS min_id_ag
        ON h1.agency_id = min_id_ag.agency_id
        AND h1.id = min_id_ag.min_id
) AS h0 
    ON hh.agency_id = h0.agency_id
WHERE hh.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' 
GROUP BY hh.created_at, hh.agency_id WITH ROLLUP
) AS t 
INNER JOIN agencies as a
on a.id = t.agency_id
```

Comment: I still get the same initial_amount for all the dates. But it ruins my other calculations(collection and pay).

Comment: OK break your query down into pieces and see what you get. If you post a dataset of say 15 rows to match the SQL table you have specified, I'll write the query.

Comment: See the updated post and the last comment. I couldn't post more links because of low reputation so I added the rest in a comment. Hope it helps. Thx.

Comment: Thanks for the extra info, from what I can see, your "Results complete sql2 is returning the correct initial_amount? Surely the initial_amount for each agent_id will be the same? Can you post a subset of data and a table of what you expect the outcome to be, then I can recreate it in its entirety. Thanks.

Comment: Yes it is but I actually posted a modified query which wasn't returning the correct values on Subquery 2. So this is the correct one: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznFME0XJpHWM3NhNmpIUW56bnM/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the original table filtered by one agency_id: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznFME0XJpHWWGZFYVo5RlpTMjQ/view?usp=sharing)

What I want is a result set grouped by agency_id per each date in a given interval, and for each day per agency to get the `initial_amount` of the first transaction on the current day.
@wkdmarty

Comment: EX: between 2015-11-25 and 26th
agency_id       initial_amount       date/created_at
1                           602                  2015-11-25
1                           2226                2015-11-26
Now i get the 602(the first initial amount) on every date. Hope you understand.

Comment: Ah ok, I think I'm getting it. You need to go back to your original SQL, the bits I suggested adding are wrong. Is it possible to post a link to some data I can import into MySQL? for example a sql dump? I'll import it and write the query.

Comment: here's an export of the 2 tables: [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BznFME0XJpHWMGZLWmc4NmczNTg/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Any luck wkdmarty?  @wkdmarty

Answer (score 0):

You answer was almost correct, definitely got me on the right track to fixing it.
Thank you very much for you help and pacience @wkdmarty!

This is the query I wanted.

```
SELECT     a.id, 
       a.NAME, 
       t.agency_id, 
       t.initial_amount, 
       Date_format(t.created_at, "%d.%m.%Y") AS date, 
       Date_format(t.created_at, "%Y-%m-%d") AS date_created, 
       t.created_at, 
       t.collection, 
       t.pay, 
       (t.initial_amount + t.collection - t.pay) AS total_amount 
FROM       ( 
                 SELECT    hh.agency_id, 
                           hh.amount, 
                           h0.initial_amount, 
                           hh.created_at, 
                           sum(IF(hh.payment_type=0,hh.amount,0)) AS collection, 
                           sum(IF(hh.payment_type=1,hh.amount,0)) AS pay 
                 FROM      house_register                         AS hh 
                 LEFT JOIN 
                           ( 
                                      SELECT     h1.initial_amount, 
                                                 h1.agency_id, 
                                                 h1.created_at 
                                      FROM       house_register AS h1 
                                      INNER JOIN 
                                                 ( 
                                                          SELECT   min(h2.id) AS min_id, 
                                                                   h2.agency_id, 
                                                                   h2.created_at 
                                                          FROM     house_register AS h2 
                                                          GROUP BY h2.agency_id, 
                                                                   h2.created_at ) AS min_id_ag
                                      ON         h1.agency_id = min_id_ag.agency_id 
                                      AND        h1.id = min_id_ag.min_id 
                                      WHERE      h1.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' ) AS h0 
                 ON        hh.agency_id = h0.agency_id 
                 AND       hh.created_at = h0.created_at 
                 WHERE     h0.created_at BETWEEN '2015-11-01' AND '2015-11-30' 
                 GROUP BY  hh.created_at, 
                           hh.agency_id WITH rollup ) AS t 
INNER JOIN agencies AS a 
ON a.id = t.agency_id 
ORDER BY t.agency_id, 
         t.created_at
```

Comment: Excellent, glad I could help, sorry it was took so long.